# Shadow is being cut off and shown in new column - CSS Masonry

Tags: html, css

As the question states, I am creating a masonry layout through CSS which works fine in first place. One thing I have noticed lately is, that the box-shadow of the last element that touches the very bottom of the grid-wrapper is being cut off and shown on the very top of this grid-wrapper. I have tried adding padding and margins and even spacing elements on the bottom, but nothing seems to work properly.

[Image of shadow cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/397LJ.png)

Hope for help! If anythings missing, I will give you the additions as soon as possible!

Very lovely greetings

```css
body {background:grey;}

:root {
    --masonry-spacer-index: 1rem;
    --masonry-columns-index: 3;
    --gap:1em;
    --columns:var(--masonry-columns-index);
}

.quote-grid { 
    width:980px;
    display:column;
    columns:var(--columns);
    gap:var(--gap);
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:orange;
}

.quote-grid > quote { 
    break-inside:avoid;
    margin-bottom:var(--gap);
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    transition:all .1s linear;
    background:white;
    padding:24px;
    box-shadow:8px 0 20px black;
}

@supports (grid-template-rows: masonry) {
    .quote-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: masonry;
        grid-auto-flow: dense;
        /* align-tracks: stretch; */
    }

    .quote-grid > * {
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-grid">

    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
    <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>

</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you add ```padding-bottom``` to your ```quote-grid```? I don't know what else you have in there aside from this table so i can't see if its replicating on my end.

Comment: It doesn't add the padding, the result still is the same weirdly. In the `quote-grid` itself there are just quote-boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Chrome/Edge.

On my Windows10 laptop Firefox gives this, the shadow is correct:
[image]

However on Chrome/Edge it gives the problem as discussed in the question:
[image]

Note: the shadow on the bottom of each entry is a lot thinner/lighter than the shadow on the bottom of each entry in the Chrome example. In fact, **the last entry is the only one that is correct!**

This seems to be related to a known problem with Chrome (hence also Edge). From [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=column):

> Chrome is reported to incorrectly calculate the container height, and often breaks on margins, padding, and can display 1px of the next column at the bottom of the previous column.

caniuse then recommends:

> Part of these issues can be solved by adding -webkit-perspective:1; to the column container. This creates a new stacking context for the container, and apparently causes chrome to (re)calculate column layout.

But forcing a new stacking context - I tried several methods - did not seem to cure the problem.

Simplifying everything and putting the shadow on an element but without the display column, using inline-block instead, the shadow does appear correct on every element. Obviously if you were to use this method the percentages would need proper care to get the same layout as with display in column, this snippet is just for illustration:

```css
<style>body {
  background: grey;
}

:root {
  --masonry-spacer-index: 1rem;
  --masonry-columns-index: 3;
  --gap: 1em;
  --columns: var(--masonry-columns-index);
}

.quote-grid {
  width: 980px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: orange;
}

.quote-grid>quote {
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: var(--gap);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .1s linear;
  background: white;
  padding: 24px;
  box-shadow: 8px 0 20px black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-grid">

  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>
  <quote>/* quote inr */</quote>

</div>
```